# Помогите пожалуйста с задачей - C++

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Элементы размещаются по возрастанию по спирали к центру по часовой
стрелке начиная от верхнего левого угла матрицы, используя пузырьковый метод сортировки

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    int size, x, y;
    int A[5][5];
    bool b = false;
    cout << "Введите размер матрицы: " << endl, cin >> size;
    if (size < 25)
    {
        cout << "Введите минимальный элемент массива: ", cin >> x, cout << "Введите максимальный элемент массива: ", cin >> y;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = x + rand() % (1 + (y - x));
                cout << A[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
        bool b;
        int temp;
        do {
            b = false;
            int k = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        if (A[i][j] < A[i - 1][j]) {
                            temp = A[i - 1][j];
                            A[i - 1][j] = A[i][j];
                            A[i][j] = temp;
                            b = true;
                        }
                        if (A[i][j] < A[i - 1][k]) {
                            temp = A[i - 1][k];
                            A[i - 1][k] = A[i][j];
                            A[i][j] = temp;
                            b = true;
                        }
                        if (A[i][j] < A[i][j - 1]) {
                            temp = A[i][j - 1];
                            A[i][j - 1] = A[i][j];
                            A[i][j] = temp;
                            b = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } while (b == true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                cout << A[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Давайте попробуем еще раз, только вежливо. Вы не написали вопрос в своем вопросе, а просто описали условие. В чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

есть алгоритм, который заполняет матрицу размерами 10 на 10 по спирали к центру числами по возрастанию...на основе этого алгоритма доделайте сортировку , правда у меня код написан на Jawa но все идентично.

```
 number=0;
      int xLf=0;
      int xRt=9;
      int yUp=0;
      int yDn=9;

      do {
          for (int i=xLf; i <=xRt ; i++ ) { spiral [yUp][i]   = number; 
              number ++ ; }; yUp++;
          for (int i=yUp; i <=yDn ; i++ ) { spiral [i]  [xRt] = number; 
             number ++ ; }; xRt-- ;
          for (int i=xRt; i >=xLf ; i-- ) { spiral [yDn][i]   = number; 
              number ++ ; }; yDn-- ;
          for (int i=yDn; i >=yUp ; i-- ) { spiral [i]  [xLf] = number; 
              number ++ ; }; xLf++ ;

      } while (number < 99); сюда код
```

Comment: для матрицы с одинаковими сторонами будет работать, если строк больше чем столбцов или наоборот то алгорится нужно дорабатывать.